# Fedex API + PHP + I want to add custom field on label..like order number

Tags: php, api, fedex

I need to create label using fedex api,

I am getting fields like date, from name, ship name.

I need to print Order number also on that label.

Comment: What have you tried so far??? Is there any test key for fedex api as a user has to register to get api key for solving your problem

Comment: Give your current code, what have you tried, and what are you stuck on?

Comment: yes.. even its creating label also

Comment: I just need to add some custom field as like order number.. so need to know how we can pass such fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a block like this after your weight/dimensions for a package...

```
<CustomerReferences> 
<CustomerReferenceType>CUSTOMER_REFERENCE</CustomerReferenceType> <Value>505042OH</Value> 
</CustomerReferences>
<CustomerReferences> 
<CustomerReferenceType>INVOICE_NUMBER</CustomerReferenceType> 
<Value>296430</Value> 
</CustomerReferences>
```